# How do I sum the counts of 2 queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
--Query 1 - Processed
select cast(a.startdate as date), count(distinct a.signatureid)
from asset a
join assetlog al on al.assetid = a.assetid
where a.stream = 50
and al.priority in ('1','3')
group by cast(a.startdate as date)
order by cast(a.startdate as date)

--Query 2 - Unprocessed
select cast(a.startdate as date), count(distinct a.signatureid)
from asset a
join assetlog al on al.assetid = a.assetid
where a.stream = 49
and a.order is not null
and al.priority = 2
group by cast(a.startdate as date)
order by cast(a.startdate as date)
```

Hi, portion of queries above which ultimately each take the count distinct of a column, per each day. One finds "processed" records, and the other finds "unprocessed". Unfortunately there's no simple column in a table that determines this.

Now need a query which sums both tables' count distinct per day. What is the best way to achieve this? BTW this in SSMS.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's worth making sure you've tagged your question appropriately.  In this instance, I'd suggest that the t-sql tag would be better than the ssms tag. And to answer your question, first consider whether efficiency or brevity is more desirable for the solution. For efficiency you might store the results of each query in a new (possibly in-memory or #temp) table, then run a query against the new table. For brevity you could write a third query which ORs the WHERE conditions of the two originals.

Answer (score 0):

If an asset can "appear" in both query 1 and query 2 for a given day, this solution would only count it once for that day:

```
--Query 1 - Processed
select cast(a.startdate as date), count(distinct a.signatureid)
from asset a
join assetlog al on al.assetid = a.assetid
where (a.stream = 50
and al.priority in ('1','3'))
or (a.stream = 49
and a.order is not null
and al.priority = 2)
group by cast(a.startdate as date)
order by cast(a.startdate as date)
```

This query is derived from the two in the question, but combines the WHERE clauses using an OR.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately what I shared was only a small portion of the actual queries. There's lines in each respective query which are incorporating tables that aren't in the other so that solution wouldn't work. I was more wondering if there is a  way involving subqueries and adding the results together, etc as I'm ultimately trying to select and group the same columns

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't combine the queries as you suggest in a comment, you could use a `full join` like the following:

```
with a ([date], [sum]) as (
    select      CAST('20180101' as date)                as  [date]
        ,       2                                       as  [sum]
    union all
    select      CAST('20180102' as date)                as  [date]
        ,       4                                       as  [sum]
)

, b ([date], [sum]) as (
    select      CAST('20180102' as date)                as  [date]
        ,       3                                       as  [sum]
    union all
    select      CAST('20180103' as date)                as  [date]
        ,       8                                       as  [sum]
)

select      ISNULL(a.[date], b.[date])                  as  [date]
    ,       ISNULL(a.[sum], 0) + ISNULL(b.[sum], 0)     as  [sum]
from        a
full join   b
    on      a.[date]                                    =   b.[date]
order by    ISNULL(a.[date], b.[date])
```